# Extracting dotnet code from standalone compiled elf

Tags: .net, reverse-engineering

I have a binary compiled with this command `dotnet publish --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --self-contained true /p:PublishSingleFile=true`, when running `file` on the result I get `ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked`.

How can I extract the original dotnet IL from the compiled binary?

I tried running `readelf` on the output, and looking at the sections I could not find one than when dumped with `objcopy` produced anything remotly like dotnet IL

Comment: Those files are platform-specific executables.